# Picker View of FUIValuePickerFormCell wont appear

Tags: ios, swift3

I've autogenerated an application from the SAP Cloud SDK Assistant, and I'd like to use a FUIValuePickerFormCell in the detail view of the application, but can't seem to do so.

I've used the sample codes given by the SAP Fiori mentor app, and added a Table View Cell of class "FUIValuePickerFormCell" in main.storyboard, but nothing happens when the cell is tapped, the pickerview doesn't come up, nor is the cell editable. Does anyone knows why is this so? Below are the codes that I used

Cell that i want to change in ProductsTypeDetailTableDelegate

```
case 6:
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUIValuePickerFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUIValuePickerFormCell
        valuePickerCell = cell
        cell.isEditable = true
        cell.keyName = "Appointment Status"
        cell.valueOptions = ["1", "2", "3"]
        cell.value = 1 //index of first value

        cell.onChangeHandler = { newValue in
            if let option = self.valuePickerCell?.valueOptions[newValue]{
                print("Selected value option \(option)")
            }
        }
        return cell
```

DetailViewController:

```
import SAPFoundation
import SAPOData
import SAPFiori
import SAPCommon
class DetailViewController: FUIFormTableViewController, Notifier, LoadingIndicator {

    private let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    private var tableDelegate: DetailTableDelegate!
    var tableUpdater: TableUpdaterDelegate?
    var loadingIndicator: FUILoadingIndicatorView?

    private let logger = Logger.shared(named: "DetailViewControllerLogger")
    var services: ServicesDataAccess {
        return appDelegate.services
    }

    // The Entity which will be edited on the Detail View
    var selectedEntity: EntityValue!
    var entityArray: [EntityValue]!
    var entityArray2: [EntityValue]!
    var entityArray3: [EntityValue]!
    var prodimages: [EntityValue]!
    var collectionType: CollectionType = .none {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = self.generatedTableDelegate() {
                self.tableDelegate = delegate
                if self.selectedEntity != nil {
                    self.tableDelegate.entity = self.selectedEntity
                }
                if self.entityArray != nil {
                    self.tableDelegate.arrayEntity = self.entityArray
                }
                if self.entityArray2 != nil {
                    self.tableDelegate.arrayEntity2 = self.entityArray2
                }
                if self.entityArray3 != nil {
                    self.tableDelegate.arrayEntity3 = self.entityArray3
                }
                if self.prodimages != nil{
                    self.tableDelegate.prodimages = self.prodimages
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        self.tableView.dataSource = tableDelegate
        self.tableView.delegate = tableDelegate

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    @IBAction func updateEntity(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.showIndicator()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.logger.info("Updating entity in backend.")
        self.services.service.updateEntity(self.tableDelegate.entity) { error in
            self.hideIndicator()

            if let error = error {
                self.logger.error("Update entry failed.", error: error)
                self.displayAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("keyErrorEntityUpdateTitle", value: "Update entry failed", comment: "XTIT: Title of alert message about entity update failure."),
                    message: NSLocalizedString("keyErrorEntityUpdateBody", value: error.localizedDescription, comment: "XMSG: Body of alert message about entity update failure."))
                return
            }

            self.logger.info("Update entry finished successfully.")
            FUIToastMessage.show(message: NSLocalizedString("keyUpdateEntityFinishedTitle", value: "Updated", comment: "XTIT: Title of alert message about successful entity update."))
            self.tableUpdater?.updateTable()
        }
    }

    func createEntity() {
        self.showIndicator()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.logger.info("Creating entity in backend.")
        self.services.service.createEntity(self.tableDelegate.entity) { error in
            self.hideIndicator()

            if let error = error {
                self.logger.error("Create entry failed.", error: error)
                self.displayAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("keyErrorEntityCreationTitle", value: "Create entry failed", comment: "XTIT: Title of alert message about entity creation error."),
                    message: NSLocalizedString("keyErrorEntityCreationBody", value: error.localizedDescription, comment: "XMSG: Body of alert message about entity creation error."))
                return
            }

            self.logger.info("Create entry finished successfully.")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    FUIToastMessage.show(message: NSLocalizedString("keyEntityCreationBody", value: "Created", comment: "XMSG: Title of alert message about successful entity creation."))
                    self.tableUpdater?.updateTable()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func cancel() -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // Test code
    private func updateTable(completionHandler: @escaping() -> Void) {

        self.tableDelegate?.requestEntities { error in

            defer {
                completionHandler()
            }

            if let error = error {
                self.displayAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("keyErrorLoadingData", value: "Loading data failed!", comment: "XTIT: Title of loading data error pop up."),
                    message: error.localizedDescription)
                self.logger.error("Could not update table.", error: error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.logger.info("Table updated successfully!")
            }
        }
    }

    private func configureView() {
        if self.collectionType != .none {
            self.title = collectionType.rawValue
            if let tableDelegate = self.generatedTableDelegate() {
                self.tableDelegate = tableDelegate
                if let tableView = self.tableView {
                    tableView.delegate = tableDelegate
                    tableView.dataSource = tableDelegate
                    self.updateTable()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func updateTable() {
        self.showIndicator()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.updateTable() {
                self.hideIndicator()
            }
        }
    }

    // test code ends
}
```

DetailTableDelegate:

```
import SAPOData
import SAPFiori
import SAPFoundation

protocol DetailTableDelegate: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var entity: EntityValue { get set }
    var arrayEntity: [EntityValue] { get set }
    var arrayEntity2: [EntityValue] { get set }
    var arrayEntity3: [EntityValue] { get set }
    var prodimages: [EntityValue] { get set}
}

extension DetailTableDelegate {
}

extension DetailViewController {

    func generatedTableDelegate() -> DetailTableDelegate? {
        switch self.collectionType {
        case .customers:
            return CUSTOMERSTypeDetailTableDelegate(dataAccess: self.services, rightBarButton: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!)
        case .suppliers:
            return SUPPLIERSTypeDetailTableDelegate(dataAccess: self.services, rightBarButton: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!)
        case .orders:
            return ORDERSTypeDetailTableDelegate(dataAccess: self.services, rightBarButton: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!, count: Int())
        case .products:
            return PRODUCTSTypeDetailTableDelegate(dataAccess: self.services, rightBarButton: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

ProductsTypeDetailTableDelegate:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SAPOData
import SAPCommon
import SAPFiori

class PRODUCTSTypeDetailTableDelegate: NSObject, DetailTableDelegate {

    private let dataAccess: ServicesDataAccess
    private var _entity: PRODUCTSType?
    // test code
    private var _arrayEntity: [PRODUCTSType] = [PRODUCTSType]()
    private var _arrayEntity2: [PRODUCTSType] = [PRODUCTSType]()
    private var _arrayEntity3: [PRODUCTSType] = [PRODUCTSType]()
    private var _prodimages: [PRODIMGType] = [PRODIMGType]()
    var valuePickerCell: FUIValuePickerFormCell?

    var prodimages: [EntityValue] {
        get {
            return _prodimages
        }
        set {
            self._prodimages = newValue as! [PRODIMGType]
        }
    }
    var arrayEntity: [EntityValue] {
        get {
            return _arrayEntity
        }
        set {
            self._arrayEntity = newValue as! [PRODUCTSType]
        }
    }
    var arrayEntity2: [EntityValue] {
        get {
            return _arrayEntity2
        }
        set {
            self._arrayEntity2 = newValue as! [PRODUCTSType]
        }
    }
    var arrayEntity3: [EntityValue] {
        get {
            return _arrayEntity3
        }
        set {
            self._arrayEntity3 = newValue as! [PRODUCTSType]
        }
    }
    // test code ends
    var entity: EntityValue {
        get {
            if _entity == nil {
                _entity = createEntityWithDefaultValues()
            }
            return _entity!
        }
        set {
            _entity = newValue as? PRODUCTSType
        }
    }
    var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem
    private var validity = Array(repeating: true, count: 8)

    init(dataAccess: ServicesDataAccess, rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dataAccess = dataAccess
        self.rightBarButton = rightBarButton
        self.rightBarButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let currentEntity = self.entity as? PRODUCTSType else {
            return cellForDefault(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        }
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Product ID"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.prodid) {
                value = "\(currentEntity.prodid)"
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.prodid, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                if let validValue = TypeValidator.validInteger(from: newValue) {
                    currentEntity.prodid = validValue
                    self.validity[0] = true
                } else {
                    self.validity[0] = false
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[0]
            })
        case 1:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Name"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.prodname) {
                if let prodname = currentEntity.prodname {
                    value = "\(prodname)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.prodname, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.prodname = nil
                    self.validity[1] = false
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validString(from: newValue, for: PRODUCTSType.prodname) {
                        currentEntity.prodname = validValue
                        self.validity[1] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[1] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[1]
            })
        case 2:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Description"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.proddesc) {
                if let proddesc = currentEntity.proddesc {
                    value = "\(proddesc)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.proddesc, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.proddesc = nil
                    self.validity[2] = false
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validString(from: newValue, for: PRODUCTSType.proddesc) {
                        currentEntity.proddesc = validValue
                        self.validity[2] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[2] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[2]
            })
        case 3:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Current Stock"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.currstock) {
                if let currstock = currentEntity.currstock {
                    value = "\(currstock)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.currstock, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.currstock = 0
                    self.validity[3] = true
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validInteger(from: newValue) {
                        currentEntity.currstock = validValue
                        self.validity[3] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[3] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[3]
            })
        case 4:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Minimum Stock"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.minstock) {
                if let minstock = currentEntity.minstock {
                    value = "\(minstock)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.minstock, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.minstock = 0
                    self.validity[4] = true
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validInteger(from: newValue) {
                        currentEntity.minstock = validValue
                        self.validity[4] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[4] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[4]
            })
        case 5:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Price"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.price) {
                if let price = currentEntity.price {
                    value = "\(price)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.price, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.price = nil
                    self.validity[5] = false
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validBigDecimal(from: newValue) {
                        currentEntity.price = validValue
                        self.validity[5] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[5] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[5]
            })
        case 6:
//            var value = ""
//            let name = "Category"
//            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.cat) {
//                if let cat = currentEntity.cat {
//                    value = "\(cat)"
//                }
//            }
//            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.cat, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
//                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
//                if newValue.isEmpty {
//                    currentEntity.cat = nil
//                    self.validity[6] = false
//                } else {
//                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validString(from: newValue, for: PRODUCTSType.cat) {
//                        currentEntity.cat = validValue
//                        self.validity[6] = true
//                    } else {
//                        self.validity[6] = false
//                    }
//                }
//                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
//                return self.validity[6]
//            })
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUIValuePickerFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUIValuePickerFormCell
            valuePickerCell = cell
            cell.isEditable = true
            cell.keyName = "Appointment Status"
            cell.valueOptions = ["1", "2", "3"]
            cell.value = 1 //index of first value

            cell.onChangeHandler = { newValue in
                if let option = self.valuePickerCell?.valueOptions[newValue]{
                    print("Selected value option \(option)")
                }
            }
            return cell

        case 7:
            var value = ""
            let name = "Supplier ID"
            if currentEntity.hasDataValue(for: PRODUCTSType.suppid) {
                if let suppid = currentEntity.suppid {
                    value = "\(suppid)"
                }
            }
            return cellForProperty(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: PRODUCTSType.suppid, value: value, name: name, changeHandler: { (newValue: String) -> Bool in
                // The property is optional, so nil value can be accepted
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    currentEntity.suppid = nil
                    self.validity[7] = true
                } else {
                    if let validValue = TypeValidator.validInteger(from: newValue) {
                        currentEntity.suppid = validValue
                        self.validity[7] = true
                    } else {
                        self.validity[7] = false
                    }
                }
                self.barButtonShouldBeEnabled()
                return self.validity[7]
            })
        default:
            return cellForDefault(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func createEntityWithDefaultValues() -> PRODUCTSType {
        let newEntity = PRODUCTSType()
        newEntity.prodid = self._arrayEntity.count + 1
        return newEntity
    }

    // Check if all text fields are valid
    private func barButtonShouldBeEnabled() {
        let anyFieldInvalid = self.validity.first { (field) -> Bool in
            return field == false
        }
        self.rightBarButton.isEnabled = anyFieldInvalid == nil
    }

    func cellForProperty(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, property: Property, value: String, name: String, changeHandler: @escaping((String) -> Bool)) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell!

        if property.dataType.isBasic {
            // The property is a key or we are creating new entity
            if (!property.isKey || self.entity.isNew) {
                // .. that CAN be edited
                cell = self.cellWithEditableContent(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, property: property, with: value, with: name, changeHandler: changeHandler)
            } else {
                // .. that CANNOT be edited
                cell = self.cellWithNonEditableContent(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, for: property.name, with: value, with: name)
            }
        } else {
            // A complex property
            cell = self.cellWithNonEditableContent(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, for: property.name, with: "...", with: name)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func cellForDefault(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> FUISimplePropertyFormCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUISimplePropertyFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUISimplePropertyFormCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = ""
        cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.keyName = "default"

        return cell
    }

    private func cellWithEditableContent(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, property: Property, with value: String, with name: String, changeHandler: @escaping((String) -> Bool)) -> FUISimplePropertyFormCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUISimplePropertyFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUISimplePropertyFormCell

        cell.isEditable = true
        cell.keyName = name
        cell.value = value

        if !property.isOptional {
            cell.valueTextField!.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("keyRequiredPlaceholder", value: "Required", comment: "XSEL: Placeholder text for required but currently empty textfield.")
        }

        cell.onChangeHandler = { (newValue) -> Void in
            if !changeHandler(newValue) {
                cell.valueTextField.textColor = UIColor.red
            } else {
                cell.valueTextField.textColor = UIColor.gray
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    private func cellWithNonEditableContent(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, for key: String, with value: String, with name: String) -> FUISimplePropertyFormCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUISimplePropertyFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUISimplePropertyFormCell

        cell.keyName = name
        cell.value = value

        return cell
    }

    private func selectKeyboardFor(_ type: DataType) -> UIKeyboardType {
        switch type.code {
        case DataType.byte, DataType.short, DataType.integer, DataType.int:
            return .decimalPad
        case DataType.decimal, DataType.double, DataType.localDateTime, DataType.globalDateTime:
            return .numbersAndPunctuation
        default:
            return .`default`
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> Double {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return Double(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return Double()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> BigDecimal {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return (defaultValue as! DecimalValue).value
        } else {
            return BigDecimal.fromDouble(Double())
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> Int {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return Int(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return Int()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> BigInteger {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return BigInteger(defaultValue.toString())
        } else {
            return BigInteger.fromInt(Int())
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> Int64 {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return Int64(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return Int64()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> Float {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return Float(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return Float()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> LocalDateTime {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return LocalDateTime.now()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> GlobalDateTime {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return GlobalDateTime.parse(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return GlobalDateTime.now()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> GuidValue {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return GuidValue.parse(defaultValue.toString())!
        } else {
            return GuidValue.random()
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> String {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return defaultValue.toString()
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func defaultValueFor(_ property: Property) -> Bool {
        if let defaultValue = property.defaultValue {
            return defaultValue.toString().toBool()!
        } else {
            return Bool()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume you are using a UITableViewController and not the FUIFormTableViewController. The events of “FUI*FormCells” are handled only by the FUIFormTableViewController, not by a UITableViewController.

Comment: I've tried changing it to FUIFormTableViewController but nothing changes, the list picker still doesnt come up.

Comment: Could you please share your detail view controller class, or even better is your project available at github?

Comment: I've edited the question and inserted the codes u need, its bascially just a copy of the master-detail application generated by the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for iOS Assistant

Comment: I could reproduce your issue. In the generated example, the colleagues have set the property “Selection” of the tableview to “No Selection”. If you change this property in your Storyboard to “Single Selection”, your picker will work.